# How can I declare string name, int age, and string location?

Tags: c++

I'm new to class in c++  and I'm getting  the message  that my variable  name, age, and location are not defined. How can I fix this? Can someone explain  it to me

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal {
private:
    string  n;
    int a;
    string s;
public:
    void set_data(string name, int age, string location ) {
        n = name;
        a = age;
        s = location;
    }
};
class  Zebra : public Animal {
public:
    void message_zebra() {
        cout << "The Zebra name is  " <<name<<"and the age  is" << age << "and the location is " << location;
    }
};
class Dolphin : public Animal {
public:
    void message_dolphin() {
        cout << "The Dolphin name is  " << name << "and the age  is" << age << "and the location is " << location;
    }
};
int main() {
    Zebra zeb;
    Dolphin dol;
    zeb.set_data("Milly", 22, "hawaii");
    dol.set_data("Kyle", 22, "detroit");
    zeb.message_zebra();
    dol.message_dolphin();
}
```

Comment: Change `private` to `public` or create [getter functions](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/learning-c-getters-and-setters-in-class-definitions-c7c0469fb63c?gi=4c0d79cb1540)

Comment: You  might find it helpful to challenge your compiler on something like this. Tell your compiler that it is wrong *(don't worry -- talking to the screen is a fine programming tradition)*. Tell it that you have defined those variables. Point to the lines where they are defined. Then present both sides of the argument (yours and your compiler's) to us in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access private member variables of the parent class.
If you want to access the variables of the parent class, they must be defined as protected or public member variables.

Also, you should use parent members variables names like `n`, `a`, `s`. Not `name`, `age`, `location`.

```
class Animal {
protected: // updated part
    string  n;
    int a;
    string s;
public:
    void set_data(string name, int age, string location ) {
        n = name;
        a = age;
        s = location;
    }
};
class  Zebra : public Animal {
public:
    void message_zebra() {
        cout << "The Zebra name is  " << n <<"and the age  is" << a << "and the location is " << s;
    }
};
class Dolphin : public Animal {
public:
    void message_dolphin() {
        cout << "The Dolphin name is  " << n << "and the age  is" << a << "and the location is " << s;
    }
};
```

Comment: @EmmilMendoza The member variable names in the base class are `n`, `a`, and `s`. Look at the names of the variables you're trying to send to `cout`.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems.

1. `#include <string>`
2. as answer above, change "private:" to "protected:"
3. cout should use the member variant as declared

```
cout << "The Zebra name is " << n <<"and the age is" << a << "and the location is " << s;
```

Comment: #include <string>

Comment: I'm sorry, There are three problems. I did't say the details.
1. #include <string>
2. as answer above, change "private:" to "protected:"
3. cout << "The Zebra name is  " << n <<"and the age  is" << a << "and the location is " << s;

I think the answer above solve the next two problems, so..

Comment: @drescherjm  It is all